# How to define a type that define an array of complex type in SOAP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a webservice method that returns an array of complex type. I have followed a lot of pages that teach how to do it, but none actually works.

Please see the WSDL at http://feriados.servicios.desytec.com/feriados?wsdl

When I call GetHolidays method from PHP, I only get a stdClass this way:

object(stdClass)#58 (0) {
}
[]

I would expect an ArrayOfFeriado type

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was that I was using soapenc namespace as stated in all sites, however, my actual namespace was SOAP-ENC.

Regards,
Jaime